# Python Tensorflow session.run() releasing GIL

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

As far as I understand (based on reading online), session.run() from Tensorflow releases the Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which typically would prevent multi-threading from working optimally in Python. If that's true, then multi-threading should provide significant performance benefits if I run multiple sessions in parallel right?

I implemented the follow code below, but it's still running the same speed as if being run sequentially. Am I implementing it incorrectly somewhere? Or is my understanding incorrect?

```
def perform_inference_threaded_second(sess, input_list, output):
    output.append(np.asarray(sess.run(y_op, {x_inp: input_list})).astype(np.float32))

def perform_inference_threaded_parent_second(input_list):
    inference_parent_start = time.perf_counter()
    output = []
    thread_list = []

    for model_idx in range(len(model_names)):
        sess = cr_sessions[model_idx]
        with sess.as_default():
            with curr_graph.as_default():                
                 t = threading.Thread(target=perform_inference_threaded_second, args=(sess, input_list, output))
                 thread_list.append(t)
                 t.start() # start thread execution

    for t in thread_list:
        t.join() # block until the thread is finished

    return output
```